# Sparrow/Twitter like UIt tab bar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there any cocoa/obj-c library or example on implementing side bars like Sparrow or Twitter for Mac client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter for Mac uses the [Twui framework](https://github.com/twitter/twui), which is based on Core Animation.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently coded something similar called `ITSidebar`.

You can check it out on Github:
https://github.com/iluuu1994/ITSidebar